# Order by oldest date from more dates in a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Each customor in my database has a own row.
For each customer i saved the product he bought and when he need a new one.
But sometimes a customer has more products like 2-3.
Example of some rows:

```
id  |  customername | product1 | dateneednew1   | product2 |dateneednew2  
1.  | Jacob ....... | a product| 2017-11-18 ... | a product| 2016-12-01
2.  | Anna ........ | a product| 2016-12-10 ....| a product| 2017-10-10
2.  | Peter ....... | a product| 2016-12-05 ... | a product| 2017-08-10
```

Now i wanna order by the oldest date of all "dateneednew1" - "dateneednew2"... , so in the example Jacob is first, Peter second and Anna last.

Comment: Badly designed database.... normalized your tables

Comment: You easily can add 'ORDER BY date ASC' in your SQL. ;-)

Comment: You can have a single row per user and per sell ! it make it easier to create scripts !

Comment: @IgorUnger true but there are more dates in my table firstbuy too.

Comment: @delato468 thats no god for working with this table. Maybe you should rethink your database structure.

Comment: I can´t use a single row because they got updated very often and i can´t search then WHERE product1 = :product. I need this structure.

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order by -

```
least(dateneednew1,dateneednew2)
```

If the columns can contain NULLs -

```
least(coalesce(dateneednew1,'3000-01-01'),coalesce(dateneednew2,'3000-01-01'))
```

If the columns can contain '0000-00-00' as default date (bad design) -

```
least(coalesce(nullif(dateneednew1,'0000-00-00'),'3000-01-01'),coalesce(nullif(dateneednew2,'0000-00-00'),'3000-01-01'))
```

Comment: Yeah i have NULLs =), hmm it doesn´t work, could be an error by me.

Comment: @RazibAlMamun no error but because of the nulls i don´t get a correct result. If i use only 1 parameter instead of 5 for LEAST it works (because there are no nulls then), something went wrong with coalesce i think. The Nulls in my database are formatted like that: 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

With two or more arguments, returns the smallest (minimum-valued) argument.

```
select *from customor order by least(dateneednew1,dateneednew2) asc;
```